# How to get the difference between two rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query which returns the below data set.

**Sample:**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE rank_code IN (15, 22);
```

The output of the above query gives the below result.

| RANK | RANK_CODE | RANK_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 15 | XYZ |
| 5 | 22 | ABC |

Now, I would like to get the difference of Rank i.e., 5-3 = 2 or 3-5 = 2 in a single query. Only the difference. Is there a way to achieve the same using a SQL Query so that I may pass the rank codes as input parameter.
And if any row is not found or cannot be fetched the final result will be 0. Can we put this little check as well?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT coalesce(max(rank) - min(rank), 0)
FROM table_name 
WHERE rank_code IN (15, 22);
```

Comment: I'd add COALESCE() around to replace null with zero ;) +1!

Comment: With `coalesce(..., 0)` around to satisfy *And if any row is not found or cannot be fetched the final result will be 0*

Comment: Wow.. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

If - in real life - that table contains many rows and you actually want to find difference between every two consecutive rows, consider one of analytic functions (`LAG` or `LEAD`). For example:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (RANK, rank_code, rank_desc)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 3, 15, 'XYZ' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 5, 22, 'ABC' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT RANK,
  8         LEAD (RANK) OVER (ORDER BY RANK) next_rank,
  9         RANK - LEAD (RANK) OVER (ORDER BY RANK) diff,
 10         --
 11         rank_code,
 12         rank_desc
 13    FROM test;

      RANK  NEXT_RANK       DIFF  RANK_CODE RAN
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
         3          5         -2         15 XYZ
         5                               22 ABC

SQL>
```

Comment: The first solution works for me.. But I would like to keep this one with me as well.. Thanks a lot for your help!! :)